How to fix error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'" when I use "from pyDOE2 import fullfact"?
I need to import “fullfact” from “pyDOE2”. But I faced with the following error: “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'”.
Phyton version: 3.12.4
I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Could you please supply your actual code in a minimal reproducable example?

The error occurred in the beginning of my code when the code reach to the command "from pyDOE2 import fullfact"

Please read the website guidelines. It really is not possible to help you with the current lack of information. Provide a minimal reproducible example.

Late reply, but might help others searching for this same issue: pyDOE3 is now available and appears to have been motivated by fixing this problem.

I'm late to reply, but I'll answer this just in case if anyone stumbles upon this issue like me.
This is going to happen if you have python version>=3.12. The reason being "imp" has been completely removed from recent python versions.
The error will look something of this sort:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 from pyDOE2 import fullfact
File c:\Users\***libpath\Lib\site-packages\pyDOE2\__init__.py:22
      1 """
      2 pyDOE original code was originally converted from code...
---> 22 from pyDOE2.doe_box_behnken import *
     23 from pyDOE2.doe_composite import *
     24 from pyDOE2.doe_factorial import *

File c:\Users\***libpath\Lib\site-packages\pyDOE2\doe_box_behnken.py:17
      1 """
      2 This code was originally published by the following individuals for use with
...
---> 16 import imp
     17 import itertools
     18 import math
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

Solution
You can go about it in 2 ways:

Either downgrade your python version to an older version i.e. <3.12
Or Find the location where Module imp is imported and replace it with importlib

I read the error message in detail and found the location of module import. The module is imported in the pyDOE library installation location in doe_factorial.py file.

c:\env_lib_path***\Lib\site-packages\pyDOE2\doe_factorial.py:16

Open the file and replace imp -> importlib there. Restart your working environment and it should resolve the ModuleNotFoundError.
Hope it helps!
